# VS Code auto-removes the "import React from 'react'" statement

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I use `shift` + `alt` + `o` to remove those unused modules I don't need anymore quite often.
It worked fine when doing so in the `.tsx` file before.

But somehow VS Code removes the `import React from 'react'` statement recently which didn't happen before.

Is it due to some updates of VS Code recently?

I found this setting below, not sure if it's related or not. But neither enabled and disabled status work.

[image]

Or any other reason that may cause this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using React v17 then no need to import `React from 'react'` in order to write JSX. You can read more here [react v17](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html)

Answer (score 1):

Because the need for adding **`import React from 'react';`** is not need with the latest react update so that it is taken out.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, we keep React 16 in the existing project.
And one viable fix is to add `jsx: 'react'` to the `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
  }
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49486#issuecomment-1157426215